# Prepend routing helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to generate urls prepended with `#!` string to load pages with ajax(sammy.js).

I have written a helper method in the `application_helper.rb`:

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  super(method, *args, &block)
rescue NoMethodError => e
  match   = method.to_s.match /^sammy_(\w*_path)$/
  prepend = '#!'
  unless match.nil?
    prepend + send(match[1].to_sym, *args, &block)
  else
    raise e
  end
end
```

It's working fine in the development environment, but gives an error in production.

```
ActionView::TemplateError (column_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"columns", :action=>"show", :id=>#<Column id: 2, author_id: 3, parent_id: nil ...>}, expected: {:controller=>"columns", :action=>"show"}, diff: {:id=>#<Column id: 2, author_id: 3, parent_id: nil ...>}) on line #3 of vendor/plugins/theme/app/views/posts/_post_box.html.erb:
1: <article class="postbox <%= 'double' if post_box_counter.zero? %>">
2:   <div class="inner">
3:     <p class="post-column"><%= link_to column.title, sammy_column_path(column) %></p>
4:     <h2><%= link_to post_box.title, sammy_column_post_path(column, post_box) %></h2>
5:     <p class="post-author"><a href="#/szerzo/1-fabian-terez"><%= post_box.author.name %></a></p>
6:     <%- link_to sammy_column_post_path(column, post_box) do -%>

    (eval):17:in `column_path'
    app/helpers/application_helper.rb:66:in `send'
    app/helpers/application_helper.rb:66:in `method_missing'
    vendor/plugins/theme/app/views/posts/_post_box.html.erb:3
    vendor/plugins/theme/app/views/columns/show.html.erb:3
    app/controllers/index_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```